# google sheets script - several multiple choice answers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialog

I am trying to make a pop-up box with several multiple-choice answers to select.

I used this example:
[google apps script : a select drop down list in google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219901/google-apps-script-a-select-drop-down-list-in-google-sheet)
Which was a good starting point for 1 question, and I tried expanding on it to get multiple answers but failed expanding it.

Here's my test file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRCqpvfRl64a7ISyuohxUJLWKbqX9Fz6NPCrL2iKEm0/

It contains script code triggered by a simple button press;

```
function start() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A10').activate();

// START HTML POP-UP
dropDownModal()
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

function dropDownModal() {
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dropdown.html')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(350)
    .setHeight(175);
    
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'Box title');
};

function writeChoice(selection1) {
  const writeResponseLocation1 = "A1";

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getRange(writeResponseLocation1)
    .setValue(selection1);
}

function writeChoice(selection2) {
  const writeResponseLocation2 = "B1";

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getRange(writeResponseLocation2)
    .setValue(selection2);
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and this dropdown.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<script>
  function onSuccess1() {
    google.script.host.close();
  }

  function submit1() {
    const choice1 = document.getElementById('choice1').value;
    const choice2 = document.getElementById('choice2').value;

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess1)
      .writeChoice(choice1)
      .writeChoice(choice2);
  }
  
  function setup1() {
    const button = document.getElementById('submitbutton1');
    button.addEventListener("click", submit1)
  }

</script>

<body onload="setup1()">
  <p>
    Text 1.
  </p>
  <form>
    <select id="choice1">
      <option value="choice 1-A">choice 1-A</option>
      <option value="choice 1-B">choice 1-B</option>
      <option value="choice 1-C">choice 1-C</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select id="choice2">
      <option value="choice 2-A">choice 2-A</option>
      <option value="choice 2-B">choice 2-B</option>
      <option value="choice 2-C">choice 2-C</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button id="submitbutton1">Hit it 1</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

and it's writing the answer from Question 1 into the location intended for Question 2.

Can someone please help find where I went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You have two functions with the same name `writeChoice`

It is not enough to change the name of the [function parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp) (`selection1`, `selection1`), indeed those are only placeholders.

Instead you need to either create two different funcitons with two different names (sample 1) or pass `writeResponseLocation` as a second parameter (sample 2).

Furthermore, with `google.script.run` you can only call one Apps Script function at a time. You can call the second one e.g. within your success handler.

**Sample 1:**

*Code.gs*

```js
...
function writeChoice1(selection1) {
  const writeResponseLocation1 = "A1";

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getRange(writeResponseLocation1)
    .setValue(selection1);
}

function writeChoice2(selection2) {
  const writeResponseLocation2 = "B1";

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getRange(writeResponseLocation2)
    .setValue(selection2);
}
...
```

*html*

```js
<script>
  function onSuccess1() {
    const choice2 = document.getElementById('choice2').value;
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess2)
      .writeChoice2(choice2);
  }
  function onSuccess2() {
    google.script.host.close();
  }
  function submit1() {
    const choice1 = document.getElementById('choice1').value;
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess1)
      .writeChoice1(choice1);
  }
  
  function setup1() {
    const button = document.getElementById('submitbutton1');
    button.addEventListener("click", submit1)
  }

</script>
...
```

**Sample 2:**

*Code.gs*

```js
...
function writeChoice(selection, writeResponseLocation) {

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getRange(writeResponseLocation)
    .setValue(selection);
}

...
```

*html*

```js
<script>
  function onSuccess1() {
    const choice2 = document.getElementById('choice2').value;
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess2)
      .writeChoice(choice2, "B1");
  }
  function onSuccess2() {
    google.script.host.close();
  }
  function submit1() {
    const choice1 = document.getElementById('choice1').value;
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess1)
      .writeChoice(choice1, "A1");
  }
  
  function setup1() {
    const button = document.getElementById('submitbutton1');
    button.addEventListener("click", submit1)
  }

</script>
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  For some reason didn't see the notification and meanwhile figured it out mostly (just posted that).

Answer (score 0):

Think I found a solution here fiddling together with a friend.

```
// =========================================================================
//
// EMPTY CELLS A1 and A2 before re-run
//
function start() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A10').activate();

// START HTML POP-UP
dropDownModal()
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

function dropDownModal() {
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dropdown.html')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(350)
    .setHeight(175);
   
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'Box title');
};

function writeChoice1(selection1) {
  const writeResponseLocation1 = "A1";

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getRange(writeResponseLocation1)
    .setValue(selection1);
}

function writeChoice2(selection2) {
  const writeResponseLocation2 = "B1";

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getRange(writeResponseLocation2)
    .setValue(selection2);
}

// =========================================================================
```

And the

dropdown.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<script>
  function onSuccess() {
    google.script.host.close();
  }

  function submit() {
    const choice1 = document.getElementById('choice1').value;
    const choice2 = document.getElementById('choice2').value;

    google.script.run
      .writeChoice1(choice1)

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .writeChoice2(choice2)
  }
  
  function setup() {
    const button = document.getElementById('submitbutton');
    button.addEventListener("click", submit)
  }
</script>

<body onload="setup()">
  <p>
    Text 1.
  </p>
  <form>
    <select id="choice1">
      <option value="choice 1-A">choice 1-A</option>
      <option value="choice 1-B">choice 1-B</option>
      <option value="choice 1-C">choice 1-C</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select id="choice2">
      <option value="choice 2-A">choice 2-A</option>
      <option value="choice 2-B">choice 2-B</option>
      <option value="choice 2-C">choice 2-C</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button id="submitbutton">Submit entries</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

This all works.

The one thing I was hoping to understand and hopefully someone here can explain.

1. Why can I not

```
google.script.run
 .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
 .writeChoice1(choice1)
 .writeChoice2(choice2)
```

2. And why does even in the working version

```
 .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
 .writeChoice2(choice2)
```

work, but this having the the closing after writing the choice not as such:

```
 .writeChoice2(choice2)
 .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
```

The confusing part is that I would assume close before writing would mean no write, so i switched them around somewhere early on in testing.

Happy the code works, but still wanting to learn if someone knows :)